# NextJS how to change URL when using rewrites

Tags: next.js

In my `nextjs`-app, I want to redirect a page to another page, by using the `rewrites`-method in the `next.config` file.

here is my config file:

```
const nextConfig = {
   reactStrictMode: true,
   async rewrites() {
     return [
       {
         source: "/categories",
         destination: "/categories/albums",
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

So what I want to achieve is that when the page `/categories` is loaded, I want to redirect to `categories/albums`. So far it works, but for some some reason though, the URL does not change e.g. the URL still says `/categories` even though it displays the `categories/albums`-page - why is that? Am I missing some further options/settings?

**UPDATE**
I found out, that I can use the `redirects`-method instead. I have to refresh the page to make it work though, which is weird - does anyone have an idea?

Comment: _"I can use the redirects-method instead. I have to refresh the page to make it work though"_ - That's expected - `redirects` only work for full page reloads, when the request goes to the server (when you access the URL directly from the browser or you refresh the page). It won't work for client-side navigations (unlike `rewrites`).

Answer (score 0):

That's what a rewrite does. I think you are looking for a [redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects):

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/categories',
        destination: '/categories/albums',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: yes exactly! But I have to refresh the page to make the URL change work!? :-/

Comment: What do you mean by that? When the user navigates to `/categories` it should be redirected to `/categories/albums`.

Comment: When I hit the `categories` route, I have to refresh/reload the page to make it switch to `categories/albums`....

Comment: Please provide a CodeSandbox or similar to reproduce the problem.